# I am not receiving first name, last name, mobile and message in contact form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

In my contact form i am receiving mail with customer email only,
I am not receiving customer first name, last name, mobile, and message. can any on help.

take a look at my code.

contact.html looking like this

```
          <div class="span8">
                <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
                <div class="show-grid row">
                    <div class="span8">
                        <div id="sucessmessage"> </div>
                    </div>

                    <form id="contact_form" method="post" action="contact.php" >
                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="span4" id="name" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="span4" id="lastname" name="lastname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="span4" id="email" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="span4" id="phone" name="phone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span12">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea class="span8" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn send-btn">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>                        
            </div>
```

and my contact.php form looking like this

```
 <?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mailer module
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These module are used when sending email from contact form
|
*/

//Get your email address
$contact_email = 'info@mywebmail.com'; //Example : Youremail.com

//Enter your email address, email from contact form will send to this addresss. Please enter inside quotes ('myemail@email.com')
define('DEST_EMAIL', $contact_email);

//Change email subject to something more meaningful
define('SUBJECT_EMAIL', 'From SME Organics contact form');
//Success Message
define('SUCCESS_MESSAGE', '<h4 class="form_thanks">Thanks! Our Team will get in touch in next 24 hours</h4>');

//Error message when message can't send
define('ERROR_MESSAGE', '<h4 class="form_thanks">Oops! something went wrong, please try to submit later.</h4>');


/*
|
| Begin sending mail
|
*/

$from_fistname = $_POST['name'];
$from_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$from_name = $from_fistname.' '.$from_lastname;
$from_email = $_POST['email'];
$mime_boundary_1 = md5(time());
$mime_boundary_2 = "1_".$mime_boundary_1;
$mail_sent = false;

# Common Headers
$headers = "";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from_name.'<'.$from_email.'>'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$from_name.'<'.$from_email.'>'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$from_name.'<'.$from_email.'>'.PHP_EOL;        // these two to set reply address
$headers .= "Message-ID: <".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."webmaster@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().PHP_EOL;                  // These two to help avoid spam-filters

# Boundry for marking the split & Multitype Headers
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "   boundary=\"".$mime_boundary_1."\"".PHP_EOL;

$message = 'Name: '.$from_name.PHP_EOL;
$message.= 'Email: '.$from_email.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$message.= 'Message: '.PHP_EOL.$_POST['comment'].PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{
    $message.= 'Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].PHP_EOL;
}
if(!empty($from_name) && !empty($from_email) && !empty($message))
{
    mail(DEST_EMAIL, SUBJECT_EMAIL, $message, $headers);
    echo SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
}
else
{
    echo ERROR_MESSAGE;
}

/*
|
| End sending mail
|
*/
?>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your code is working fine.  try ` print_r($_POST);` in your `contact.php`